# No ethernet connection available in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, internet, ethernet

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a clean SSD alongside windows to do C development and when I first booted, there was no internet connection yet my ethernet worked perfectly in windows.

My network controller is the realtek RTL8125 2.5 gb and is labelled "UNCLAIMED" when I run the lshw -C network command. I can access the internet using a USB tether to my phone but nothing I have tried so far has fixed the problem.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: You need to install r8168-dkms: `apt install r8168-dkms`

Comment: @Serafim Why do you think `r8168-dkms` is needed?

Comment: @Pilot6 It is listed on https://reposcope.com/package/r8168-dkms as the driver for RTL8125

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I had this same problem after update nvidia drivers for linux. Solved just going to windows and then back to linux (have two different HDs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i had the same exact issue. i was missing drivers for the Ethernet.

Go to [Realtek site](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) from the actual Ethernet provider. Download the "*2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 5.6*" and follow the install instruction.

You should be able to use wired connection once your done.

Comment: Downloaded the exact same driver, uncompressed it, ran ./autorun.sh as sudo and now I have Ethernet on my linux distribution Pop!_OS.  This answer worked great!

Answer (score 3):

This driver exists on the ubuntu repositories, the package is called:
r8168-dkms. Yes, this works for the realtek 8125 wired ethernet connection.